# unidirectional One-To-Many association error using Spring, Hibernate, Postgres

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, heroku

I have a unidirectional one-to-many association between my customer class:

```
@Entity
public class Customer
{
@Id
  private String username;
  private String password;
  private String email;
  private String address;

  //Customer Associations

  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn
  private List<Commission> commission;

  public void setOrder(List<Commission> commission) {
    this.commission = commission;
  }
  public List<Commission> getOrder() {
    return commission;
  }
```

and my Commission class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Commission
{
@Id
  private int confirmationNumber;
  private int totalCost;
}
```

, that has two subclasses PickupCommission:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Entity
public class PickupCommission extends Commission
{
  public enum PaymentMethod { CreditCard, Cash }

  @Enumerated
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private PaymentMethod paymentMethod;

  //PickupOrder State Machines
  public enum PickupStatus { InCart, Ordered, Prepared, PickedUp }
  @Enumerated
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private PickupStatus pickupStatus;
}
```

and DeliveryCommission. After resetting my database, upon building, it gives these warnings that the constraint is not satisfied

```
2022-04-03 14:05:40.203  WARN 100664 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
2022-04-03 14:05:40.203  WARN 100664 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : constraint "uk_s7b06wqh28tqbx18olmo4imub" of relation "delivery_commission" does not exist, skipping
2022-04-03 14:05:40.248  WARN 100664 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
2022-04-03 14:05:40.248  WARN 100664 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : constraint "uk_68kai2aylxi2nv5vv3ae02a9p" of relation "pickup_commission" does not exist, skipping
```

In my controller, when I create a PickupCommission, I create it, then I add it to the Customer commissions list as such:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
public class PickupOrderRestController {
@PostMapping(value = { "/pickupOrder", "/pickupOrder/" })
    public PickupOrderDTO createPickupOrder(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String paymentMethod, @RequestParam String accountType) throws IllegalArgumentException {

        System.out.println("1");
        PickupCommission p = service.createPickupOrder(username, paymentMethod, accountType);
        System.out.println("2");
        System.out.println(customerService.getCustomerOrders(username));
        System.out.println("3");
        if (accountType.equals("Customer")) customerService.addOrder(username ,p);
        System.out.println("4");
        return convertToDto(p);
    }
```

It prints all the way to 3, finishes the addOrder function, but leaving the add order function, raises the following error and does not print 4

```
2022-04-03 14:00:12.424  WARN 98676 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2022-04-03 14:00:12.426 ERROR 98676 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "commission" does not exist
  Position: 8
2022-04-03 14:00:12.428  INFO 98676 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2022-04-03 14:00:12.461 ERROR 98676 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "commission" does not exist
  Position: 8
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2674) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2364) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:354) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:484) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:404) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:162) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:130) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.insertRows(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1588) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister.insertRows(OneToManyPersister.java:194) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionUpdateAction.execute(CollectionUpdateAction.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1402) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:493) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3285) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2420) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at ca.mcgill.ecse321.GroceryStore.service.CustomerService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5ec61a3b.addOrder(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at ca.mcgill.ecse321.GroceryStore.controller.PickupOrderRestController.createPickupOrder(PickupOrderRestController.java:33) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I have tried changing serveral other functions in the process when it was creating the pickup order, but it really seems to be a problem with adding it to the list. Right now I am thinking that it as problem with the JPA tag choice for the associations thats making it not be modifiable like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, it's because it was only a one way association; made it bidirectional with a mapped by, when i create a commission now, it gets a customer added to it, and it gets added to the customers list of commissions

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).